# Xamarin: Error MT2002

Tags: compiler-errors, xamarin

I am having this error when preparing to distribute. Simulator works fine.

> Error MT2002: Failed to resolve assembly: 'System.Security,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   (MT2002)

I am using

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace inbox{
  public class conn{
    private void conectar(){
       private ExchangeService serv;        
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did System.CodeDom and Microsoft.Exchange come from?  You cannot just use any arbitrary dll with Xamarin.

Comment: Hi Jason. I have deleted CodeDom from the code and I have downloaded Microsoft.Exchange using 'Add packages ..." from the Official Nuget Library ...The library is working well in debug mode but not when i try to create the ad-hoc app. Thanks in advance

Comment: use Xamarin's [Scan tool](http://scan.xamarin.com) to determine if a dll is compatible with Xamarin or not.

Comment: Report say is 99% compatible [link]http://scan.xamarin.com/Home/Report?scanId=27cdd1ca-ea98-42b8-b852-7067c5558c52[link] .I am lost. I have no idea how to solve the problem... Thanks

Comment: Pastebin the full build output, that might help us figure the problem out.